# Problema con ngFor en Angular: Cambiar la opacidad de elementos basados en condiciones

Tags: angular, ionic

Tengo una estructura de datos que se parece a esto:

```
[
  {
    numero: "24B",
    estado: "jalisco",
    pais: "Mexico",
    foto: "si",
    lista: "rojo"
  },
  {
    numero: "24B",
    estado: "michoacan",
    pais: "Mexico",
    lista: "rojo"
  }
]
```

Quiero iterar sobre estos elementos usando *ngFor en Angular y cambiar la opacidad de los elementos según ciertas condiciones. Las condiciones son las siguientes:

Si alguno de los elementos en la lista tiene foto: "si", entonces todos los elementos con la misma combinación de numero y lista deben tener una opacidad de 1. En otras palabras, si uno de ellos tiene una foto, todos deben tener opacidad 1.

Si ninguno de los elementos en la lista tiene foto: "si", entonces todos los elementos con la misma combinación de numero y lista deben tener una opacidad de 0.5.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of item">
  <ion-label [style.opacity]="subItem.foto === 'si' ? 1 : 0.5">
    <ion-img [src]="'/assets/' + subItem.lista + '.png'"></ion-img>
  </ion-label>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías procesar el arreglo de items y agregarle a todos los elementos la propiedad `foto`:

```js
const item = [
  {
    numero: '24B',
    estado: 'jalisco',
    pais: 'Mexico',
    foto: 'si',
    lista: 'rojo',
  },
  {
    numero: '24B',
    estado: 'michoacan',
    pais: 'Mexico',
    lista: 'rojo',
  },
  {
    numero: '24B1',
    estado: 'michoacan',
    pais: 'Mexico',
    lista: 'rojo',
  },
].map((item, _, array) => ({
  ...item,
  foto: array.find((i) => i.numero == item.numero)?.foto ?? 'no',
}));

console.log(item)
```